# Provisioning 3rd party Azure integrated application SPN

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Let's say there is a web application in some other Azure AD directory configured for multi-tenant access.
When I try to use it, after authenticating it will present a consent page asking if app can access by profile data etc. After I accept, application spn's get provisioned in my Azure AD directory.

My question is, can this consent flow be completed/accepted using graph api's programatically instead without needing interactive process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such API we can grant the consent for the permission. However it is able to grant the consent for the all organization using the parameter `prompt=admint_consent`.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) about more detail about this paramter.